# como terminar programa no windows a partir do matlab?

Tags: windows, batch, matlab

Existe alguma forma de terminar um programa no windows a partir de um comando no matlab?
Possivelmente recorrendo a um batch... mas não conheço os comandos para gerir programas no windows nem como o executar a partir do matlab.

Posso ter varias instâncias do mesmo programa, quero terminar todas menos a mais recente.

Mais detalhes: durante um ciclo em matlab um programa no windows (Xfoil) é iniciado milhares de vezes com parâmetros de entrada diferentes. Conforme os paramâtros o programa pode bloquear ou entrar em ciclo infinito. Após um tempo determinado, o ciclo matlab parte para a próxima iteração, abrindo uma nova instância do mesmo programa, mas o programa anterior continua a correr, ocupando o processador. Por vezes acumulam-se dezenas bloqueando completamente o computador.

Comment: Você podia mostrar a parte do código em que você inicia o Xfoil. Isso ajudaria.

Comment: Não sei exactamente pois uso um programa Matlab intermédio que ultrapassa os meus conhecimentos [link] (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30478-xfoil-matlab-interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei se há alguma forma mais automática para resolver isso, 
mas acho que isso resolve seu problema.

Primeiramente, você deve localizar qual é o nome do processo que está sendo executado em seu código (acredito que seja `xfoil.exe`).

Então, você deve manter o código abaixo rodando **paralelamente** ao seu código **ou** adaptá-lo de forma que seja executado entre uma execução e outra do `xfoil` no seu programa.

```
% Armazenará os IDs dos processos ativos.
pids_alive = containers.Map('KeyType','int32','ValueType','double');

% O tempo de verificação:
kill_time = 3; % 3 segundos

% O nome do processo que será encerrado.
nome_do_processo = 'xfoil.exe';

% O comando que encerrará o processo.
tasklist_cmd = sprintf('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %s" /nh /fo CSV > xfoils_running.csv', nome_do_processo);

% Loop ou Método que verificará a cada X secs o tempo
while 1 

    ids = keys(pids_alive);
    tempos = values(pids_alive);

    % Mata todos os processos que estavam rodando na passo anterior:
    for i = 1:length(ids)
        if (cputime - cell2mat(tempos(i))) > (0.1 * kill_time)
            % Comando que mata o processo.
            cmdkiller = sprintf('taskkill /f /pid %d', cell2mat(ids(i)));
            system(cmdkiller);

            % Remove o ID da lista.
            remove(pids_alive, cell2mat(ids(i)));
        end
    end

    % Lista os processos atualmente rodando.
    % Salva a lista dos processos encontrados no arquivo
    % xfoils_running.csv.
    system(tasklist_cmd)

    % Lê a lista criada.
    fid = fopen('xfoils_running.csv', 'r');

    while not(feof(fid))
        % Lê uma linha do arquivo.
        tline = fgetl(fid);

        % Lê uma linha da lista de processos.
        res = textscan(tline,'%q%q%q%q%q','delimiter',',');

        % Se não encontrar nenhum processo vivo.
        if isempty(res{2})
            continue;
        end

        % Lê ID do processo.
        pid = str2num(cell2mat(res{2}));

        % Armazena o contador tempo de vida do processo
        % se ainda não estava sendo monitorado.
        if isempty(find(cell2mat(ids) == pid))
            pids_alive(pid) = cputime;
        end
    end

    % Encerra o arquivo anterior.
    fclose(fid);

    % Espera 1 segundo
    pause(1)
end
```

---

O que resolve, basicamente, o problema são os comandos `tasklist`, usado para listar os processos ativos e obter o ID dos prossos:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq xfoil.exe" /nh /fo CSV > xfoils_running.csv
```

A partir daí, é só monitorar o tempo que esses processos vivem. Se o tempo for maior do que o que você acredita ser o limite, você mata o processo pelo ID usando `taskkill`:

```
taskkill /f /pid ####
```

Answer (score 0):

"tskill "nomedoprocesso" sem aspas

Comment: Oi, bemvindo ao [pt.so], será que você pode explicar melhor sua solução?  Confira o guia [answer]. Você pode [edit] a resposta a qualquer momento.

Comment: tenho vários processos com o mesmo nome, quero terminar todos menos o mais recente, tem forma de fazer isso?